# Enable/disable debugger support for the currently running JVM from Java code

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, jmx

Is there an interface (maybe part of JMX) that I can use to dynamically enable or disable the JVM debugger support from Java code inside that JVM?

(See also [Debug a java application without starting the JVM with debug arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376201/debug-a-java-application-without-starting-the-jvm-with-debug-arguments) —CRM)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question but I worded it differently the answer I got was there is a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376201/debug-a-java-application-without-starting-the-jvm-with-debug-arguments)

using the [jsadebugd](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jsadebugd.html?bcsi-ac-23BCAB4B72BE8863=1864FEB6000002034t3hQQ0yQeoeqQa1Q3HB4zHoGy/ODQAAAwIAAENm7AAQDgAAJQAAAJUtDwA=)