# Java API to turn on debugging in a running JVM

Tags: java, debugging, jpda

Is there a programmatic way to turn on debugging in a running JVM instance? I am looking for an API that would make a running JVM, a debug server. The API would do the equivalent of

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=<host:port>,server=y,suspend=n.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach to any running JVM using [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/download.html).  Be sure to download version 1.3.2 and install *all* the plugins.

Comment: +1 Correct! This should work at least when the JVM was started under the same user as VisualVM (or if permissions are appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

The debug port that the questioner refers to is for source code debugging, such as with an Eclipse debugger.  The port for VisualVM is the JMX port, which takes a different set of JVM options.  There are exceptions though: Mission Control for JRockit uses the jdwp port rather than the JMX port.

And yes, you can dynamically load the JMX debugger in code.   Its complicated but [OSGI](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) can load this dynamically I believe.  [For example, here is a reference to Jetty project doing this.](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-579)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The JVM has to know from the beginning that it is in debug mode. It runs a bit slower then but provides external processes with debug information and breakpoints which is not possible when the JVM already has been startet.

Comment: Daniel, I agree. I was hoping there was such an API. For what I am trying to achieve, I fully assume that the target JVM is not yet in debug mode, and that I would manage to get some code executed in it that would switch that VM to debug mode. After I know the exact port number the VM has started listening on, I would write that information to a well-known location that users of debuggers would consult and use for attaching their debuggers to that VM.