# Custom error reporting: how to log down function arguments (and possibly locals) in an exception handler?

Tags: java, logging, reflection, error-reporting

I'd like to write a generic exception handler that would report not only the exception and stacktrace, but also function arguments for all the functions in the stacktrace. If it would be possible for locals and `this` object as well, it would be just awesome. I'm thinking of writing my own some-kind-of poor man's [Takipi](https://www.takipi.com/). How could I achieve this?

Comment: In [Takipi docs](http://support.takipi.com/performance-overhead/) they say that Takipi is written in C++, so they might do stuff that's impossible with plain Java. But my question remains open :)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the [Java Debug Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/)  to capture [function arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html#getArgumentValues()), [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html#thisObject()), and [locals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html#visibleVariables()) for all the functions in the [stacktrace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ThreadReference.html#frames()).  It requires launching the JVM with the [debugger on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934571/java-api-to-turn-on-debugging-in-a-running-jvm).

Otherwise, you could use [instrumentation agents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) to modify the byte codes of methods to capture the information for use in your exception handler.