# Is it possible to enable debug for a Java process after it is started without debug

Tags: java, debugging, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debug a java application without starting the JVM with debug arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376201/debug-a-java-application-without-starting-the-jvm-with-debug-arguments)

For example, can the debug mode be enabled in JVM itself by code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **no** - if the JVM was not started with the debug option you can't connect to its debug port.

There may be special profiler type JVMs that allow it, but it's not possible with any of the standard JMVs - for obvious security reasons.