# Can I enable an address to debug in a deployed JBoss application?

Tags: java, debugging, jboss, jboss6.x, jvm-arguments

I'm working on an `JBoss 6.1` environment, which the default options doesn't enable the debug, and everybody sometimes forget to add that option on the deploy. I was wondering if `there is a way to enable the debug in an already deployed JBoss`... That would be very helpful, depending on the project, restarting the application can last 3 hours! Also, I am using Seam 3.0 (I don't know if that could help in some way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the answer: [Debug a java application without starting the JVM with debug arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376201/debug-a-java-application-without-starting-the-jvm-with-debug-arguments).

There aren't any JBoss-specific solutions.