# How to debug Java code running in a JVM embedded in native code?

Tags: java, c++, gdb, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have been asked to debug some C++ shared library that relies on Java libraries by loading an embedded Java virtual machine. The [invocation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) of the Java Native Interface (JNI) is used for that purpose.

The JVM is loaded using the `JNI_CreateJavaVM` and Java components are then invoked from C++.

I have the source code for both Java and C++ libraries.

I am using gdb as my debugger (I am working on a remote Linux environment) but it doesn't seem to support stepping in the invoked Java code.

My question is, are there any tool or workaround that could make that possible?

**Note:** My question is similar to a previous one posted in 2017, [How to debug Java code running inside native code-created JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593979/how-to-debug-java-code-running-inside-native-code-created-jvm). However, the answer focuses on using Eclipse.

Comment: Try starting the JVM with the extras argument in the linked answer when calling `JNI_CreateJavaVM` and then uses JDB from the command line to attach to it (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I passed the `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n` option to `JNI_CreateJavaVM` and I was able to attach to it running `jdb --attach 8000`. Have a great day.