# Enable java remote debug in code

Tags: java, remote-debugging

For example, we can enable java remote debug by adding following to command line.

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

But my application is running in yarn, I'm not sure which port is available.

So I want enable java debug in my code.

First I detect a available port and log in my program, then I can use this port to debug my application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debug a java application without starting the JVM with debug arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376201/debug-a-java-application-without-starting-the-jvm-with-debug-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address property specifies host (optionally) and port (only the port if host is left out). So `address=5005` specifies the port 5005 in your case. If you want your program to wait until you connect your debugger, switch `suspend=n` to `suspend=y`.

Edit:
Maybe I misunderstood your question. In case you want to enable debugging programmatically, this won't be possible as the debugging facility JPDA is not exposing a Java API nor any other way to start and stop it programmatically.

Comment: So it is impossible to do this?

Comment: As stated: No, it's not possible to start a debugger after the JVM has started your program. Same is true for stopping the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this can be done from code; however according to [an answer to this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/376276/1622527), it *is* possible to enable debugging for an already-running JVM using [jsadebugd](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jsadebugd.html)

As mentioned in said answer, the feature is marked experimental and unsupported so your mileage may vary.

Comment: jsadebugd enables remote connection of some debugging tools like jmap, jinfo and jstack. They help in some areas of debugging, but not the in the same way jpda jdb do. BTW it is possible to connect jdb to any running process (regardless of -agentlib:jdwp... setting), but that can be used to inspect few things and freezes the running application. Uncertain if that is what the author of this question wanted to do.